# Install ipa on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes, ipa

I am trying to install an .ipa on iPhone. This app need to be tested before publishing.

First, I tried to install the .ipa using iTunes. I clicked on install, it went to will install and then "installing" and is stuck there. Nothing is happening. If I try "sync", it appears as the app is being installed on the device, but disappears after the sync.

Trying installation using Xcode gives the error "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

Comment: Are your talking about your own developed App, that you are trying to install ? Or facing problem with Installation of App store app? Developed in Xcode or any other tool like ionic...?

Comment: Yes, self developed app

Comment: Have you added the UDID of your iPhone to the provisioning profile of your app?

Comment: added the UDID and it worked! thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to install your own developed app in iOS device and facing this problem, then there can be any of following reasons for this error.

> 1. You may have not created proper IPA file. Regenerate your IPA file again.
> 2. You are trying to install app in iOS device which is not registered/associated with your app in developer account. Get UDID of
>      your iOS device and register it with your app in developer account. Update your provisioning profile and regenerate your IPA.
> 3. Problem with App Installation medium you are using to install an app i.e Diawi or any other..  Re-upload your IPA file (update IPA file
>      on source location).

Go through each, one-by-one. You will get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps.

1. Create developer certificate and add in your project.
2. certificate must contain your device UDID.
3. Clean and build your project.
4. Make zip of your project .app file
5. Upload zip file to diawi https://www.diawi.com
6. Scan bar code and open link in safari browser only.
7. Click on install button.

Ref 
1. https://mobileroadie.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200091736-iOS-Developer-Account-Step-by-Step-Guide

This method never stucks.